# Concatenating two hashmaps without removing common entires from both the maps

Tags: java, hashmap

I have two hashmaps, in particular vocabs of two languages say english and german.I would like to concatenate both these map to return a single map.I tried :

```
 hashmap.putall()
```

But, removed some of the entries which are common in both maps and replace it by single entry only.But i want to keep both the vocabs intact just concatenate those. Is there any method to do it? if not any other way to do. I would prefer any methods in hashmap.

[EDIT]

To make more clear, lets see two maps

```
      at the 500    um die 500
      0   1   2     0   1   2
```

resutls into

```
  at the  500 um die 500
  0   1    2   3  4   5
```

Comment: What are your keys and what are your values?

Comment: Ugh... What would you expect `hashMap.get(key)` to return after the merge?

Comment: Hashmap does not support duplicate keys. So it will override the earlier ones with the new keys.

Comment: So for you, the order of the elements in each map must be retained in the resulting concatenated map, correct? I really hope you're using a LinkedHashMap to begin with, otherwise you're screwed in the first place. What are the keys of your map? Integers? If that's the case, you should probably be using Lists instead of Maps.

Comment: yes the order must be maintained..my keys are strings and values are integers

Comment: Well, then just use List instead. I'll post an answer with that.

Comment: Actually, you can only use Lists if your keys satisfy all the following conditions: The keys start at 0. The keys are a sequence (eg: 0, 1, 2, 3, etc...). There are no holes in the sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do that directly with any `Map` implementation, since in a map, each key is unique.

A possible workaround is to use `Map<Key, List<Value>>`, and then do the concatenation of your maps manually. The advantage of using a List for the concatenated map, is that it will be easy to retrieve each of the individual values without any extra fiddling.

Something like that would work:

```
public Map<Key, List<Value>> concat(Map<Key, Value> first, Map<Key, Value> second){
    Map<Key, List<Value>> concat = new HashMap<Key, List<Value>>();
    putMulti(first, concat);
    putMulti(second, concat);
    return concat;
}

private void putMulti(Map<Key, Value> content, Map<Key, List<Value>> dest){
    for(Map.Entry<Key, Value> entry : content){
        List<Value> vals = dest.get(entry.getKey());
        if(vals == null){
            vals = new ArrayList<Value>();
            dest.put(entry.getKey(), vals);
        }
        vals.add(entry.getValue());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You'll have to write your own custom "putAll()` method then. Something like this would work:

```
HashMap<String> both = new HashMap<String>(english);

for(String key : german.keySet()) {
    if(english.containsKey(key)) {
        both.put(key, english.get(key)+german.get(key));
    }
}
```

This first copies the English `HashMap`. Then puts in all the German words, concatenating if there is a duplicate key. You might want some kind of separator character like a `/` in between so you can later extract the two.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't anything like that in the Java main library itself, you will have to use something provided by third parties  like Google Guava's [Multimap](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release03/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html), it does exactly what you want, or build something like this manually.

You can download the Guava library [at the project's website](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/). Using a multimap is the same as using a map, as in:

```
Multimap<String,String> both = new ArrayListMultimap <String,String>();
both.putAll( german );
both.putAll( english);

for ( Entry<String,String> entry : both.entrySet() ) {
  System.out.printf( "%s -> %s%n", entry.getKey(), entry.getValue() );
}
```

This code will print all `key-value` pairs including the ones that are present on both maps. So, if you have `me->me` at both `german` and `english` they would be printed twice.

Comment: ...How does `Multimap` do what the OP wants?

Comment: A multimap is a collection that allows you to have many values for the same key, exactly what he is looking for, instead of concatenating values as the other answers are showing.

Comment: The OP specifies that he wants concatenation.  `Multimap` doesn't provide that.

Comment: Well, looks like he wants to concatenate the maps, not concatenate the strings in the values.

Comment: ...That's not how I read the OP, but okay, I can accept that this is an answer to a valid reading of the original question.  +1.

Comment: i want to just concatenate two maps, end to end adding only .

Answer (score 1):

Similar to @tskuzzy's answer

```
Map<String, String> both = new HashMap<String, String>();

both.putAll(german);
both.putAll(english);
for (String e : english.keySet()) 
    if (german.containsKey(e))
        both.put(e, english.get(e) + german.get(e));
```

Answer (score 1):

Slight improvisation of @tskuzzy and @Peter's answer here. Just define your own `StrangeHashMap` by extending `HashMap`.

```
public class StrangeHashMap extends HashMap<String, String> {
    @Override
    public String put(String key, String value) {
        if(this.containsKey(key)) {
            return super.put(key, super.get(key) + value);
        } else {
            return super.put(key, value);
        }
    }
}
```

You can use it as so:

```
Map<String, String> map1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
map1.put("key1", "Value1");
map1.put("key2", "Value2");

Map<String, String> map2 = new HashMap<String, String>();
map2.put("key1", "Value2");
map2.put("key3", "Value3");

Map<String, String> all = new StrangeHashMap();

all.putAll(map1);
all.putAll(map2);

System.out.println(all);
```

The above prints the below for me:

```
{key3=Value3, key2=Value2, key1=Value1Value2}
```

Answer (score 1):

Given the new elements in the question, it seems that what you actually need to use is lists. In this case, you can just do:

```
List<String> english = ...;
List<String> german = ...;
List<String> concat = new ArrayList<String>(english.size() + german.size());
concat.addAll(english);
concat.addAll(german);
```

And there you are. You can still use `concat.get(n)` to retreive the value nth value in the concatenated list.